# opencv cv2.calibrateCamera error

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to calibrate my camera on opencv. I have try this code that works fine and recognize the points on the CHessboard, but i have an error occuring when trying to calibrate the camera.Im am using python 3.6

I get this error:

```
error: C:\projects\opencv- 
python\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\calibration.cpp:3334: error: (-215) 
nimages > 0 in function cv::calibrateCamera
```

This is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

numero = 25
nx = 9
ny = 6
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((nx*ny,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:ny,0:nx].T.reshape(-1,2)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

#image adress
img = cv2.imread('captureL'+ str(numero)+'.png')

#color to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#find and draw ChessboardsCorners
ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray,(nx,ny),None  )

if ret == True:
    cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)   
    draw_chess = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (nx,ny), corners, ret)
    cv2.imshow('video testR',draw_chess)

    #camera calibration
    ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)



cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Do you have any idea about it? I do not have hairs anymore because of it. Thanks.

Comment: First thing I'd do is check the value of the parameters I pass to`calibrateCamera`. What is the actual value of `objpoints`, `imgpoints`, and `gray.shape[::-1]` at that point?

Comment: Thank you `@Dan Mašek`. My value for `gray.shape[::-1]` is (1920, 1080), but I notice than my values pour `objpoints` and `imgpoints` are Null.

Comment: It looks like you skipped a step there and forgot to populate those two arrays. Go through the tutorial again.

Comment: Yes, I added `objpoints.append(objp)` and `imgpoints.append(corners)` to give a value to them. Now the fonction returns the camera matrix and all the others informations correctly. My error message has gone :). Thank you again

Comment: Great, glad it helped. Feed free to write up what you learned in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I added objpoints.append(objp) and imgpoints.append(corners) to give a value to them. Now the fonction returns the camera matrix and all the others informations correctly. My error message has gone.